# get_template_part() to render single page Theme

Tags: loop, pages, page-template, get-template-part

I´m developing a single page theme and want to render all pages with their respective templates on a single page. I know I could make a query and write the markup for the respective page, but I prefer separate all templates in files. What I want is to make the loop and load the template-*.php file for each page. Is that possible?

To clarify this a little bit, below follows an example of what I want:

```
$query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('post_type=page');
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    get_template_part('templates', 'template_slug');
endwhile;
```

and in the while loop output not only the content, but the content in teh right markup.

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: Well, have you tried running it? Did it not work? :)

Comment: Hi @Rarst, it did work. I forgot to update the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if you want to call mytemplate.php:

```
get_template_part( 'template');
```

Or something like this if you want to call content-mytemplate.php:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'mytemplate' );
```

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input @pendjer What I want to know is how to put the get_template_path() method inside the while loop. I updated my question to illustrate this.